Rewrite docs.php.net URLs
Judging from these edits I made (listed below), removing "docs" from the URL fixes the link. For example, http://docs.php.net/book.mysql becomes https://www.php.net/book.mysql.

edit 1
edit 2

There are thousands more posts, likely more across the network. Can the URL be rewritten automatically? I would also suggest changing them to HTTPS.
I did not check too many posts to see if there were times this didn't fix the link, but it's certainly not possible to make them more broken than they are now.

1775 current results on a network-wide search.

It's definitely possible for staff to do this automatically, it's already been done for PHP's docs before. Hopefully it doesn't become a yearly tradition...

It's very not-cool that they broke those URLs without a redirect. Although according to this random ticket, "docs.php.net is special, and mostly intended to have an early
preview of the manual", which suggests that maybe it should never have been used... but it doesn't look like that was indicated anywhere on the domain itself, so how could people know?  It's not like it was called "docs-staging" or "docs-nightly" or similar.
